# Align \blacksquare

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

How can I align the `\blacksquare` symbol to `\Circle`?

[image]

Comment: Please, can you put your tex complete code of your drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `\Circle` comes from `wasysym`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareSymbolFont{wasysym}{U}{wasy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Circle}{\mathord}{wasysym}{35}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BlackSquare}{{\mathpalette\adapt@to@Circle\blacksquare}}
\newcommand{\adapt@to@Circle}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$#1\Circle$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$#1#2$}%
  \raisebox{-0.5\dimexpr\ht\tw@-\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$P\{X,Y \mid \Circle,\BlackSquare\}$

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}% for the demonstration
\fbox{$\Circle\BlackSquare$}
\fbox{$\scriptstyle\Circle\BlackSquare$}
\fbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\Circle\BlackSquare$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that symbols from `wasysym` don't scale in subscripts and superscripts, so I chose to implement `\Circle` in a different way.